# How to format date with "." or "/" or "-" in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA,  I'm trying to format the date that I have in the cell C3 equal  "01.30.18" to "MM/DD/YYYY".

Sometimes in the same cell I have the value like:
"01.30.18" or "01/30/18" or "01/30/2018".

I need to create a formula to format the values that I'll receive in this cell to "mm/dd/yyyy" .

I tried cDate or Format function but didn't worked
:

```
  Dim strBalancingBy As String

  Range("C3").Select

  strBalancingBy = ActiveCell.Value

   ActiveCell.Value = Format(DateValue(strBalancingBy), "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Give me the wrong result = "12/30/1899".

OR

```
ActiveCell.Value = CDate(strBalancingBy)
```

Give me the wrong result = "1/0/1900  1:30:18 AM"

Someone Can help me with this formula in vba?

I expect the result = "01/30/2018"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the `.` with `/`

```
With Range("C3")
    .Value = DateValue(Replace(.Value, ".", "/"))
    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End With
```

Comment: Thanks you so much :)

Comment: @MiriamLara if this worked for you, please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.